# Data FROM fragment TO activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity, start-activity

I'm trying to pass data from a fragment to an activity using a method in the Activity:

```
public void setID(int i,int j) {
    theme = i;
    thread = j;
}
```

and then, from the fragment I use the Intent to create the activity and pass the data with:

```
private class ListItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        int pos=position+1;
        ThreadActivity threadactivity = new ThreadActivity();
        threadactivity.setID(id,pos);
        Intent q = new Intent(getActivity(), threadactivity.getClass());
        startActivity(q);
    }
}
```

but, when the activity starts the values of "i" and "j" are 0. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: please have a look on this [fragments/communicating](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: use interface to send message from fragment to activity .That is good thing when you going to handle multi screen

Comment: **Never** create instances of `Activities` yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The activity you created and the one you started with the intent are different. You should pass the parameters into the intent and then get them back in the activity.

```
 private class ListItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
    { 

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, threadactivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("theme", id);
    intent.putExtra("thread", pos);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

then in the onCreate of the activity you would do something like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...


    theme = (int) getIntent().getExtras().get("theme");
    thread = (int) getIntent().getExtras().get("thread");


    }
```

Comment: Oh my, that simple. I tried with the extras but I didn't know how to call them from the Activity. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

This `ThreadActivity threadactivity = new ThreadActivity();` is pointless because you don't control the creation of activity. The system does. So all data transfer between activities is done through intent, not getter and setter.

```
  Intent q = new Intent(getActivity(),ThreadActivity.class);
  q.putExtra("theme", i);
  q.putExtra("thread" j);
  startActivity(q);
```

Then you get the values in the next activity using `getIntent().getIntExtra(VARNAME, defaultValue)`;

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way to pass data to activity. Use `Intent` to pass data. 
Read this:
http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/241-lesson-28-extras-passing-data-using-intent.html

Answer (score 0):

Please use like below

```
((YourActivity)getActivity()).yourMethod();
```

yourMethod() is declared in Activity.